# React custom type definition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in React, and I got an issue with a custom type definition in my React app. I learn with the Stoyan Stefanov book, and there is an example of a custom type definition, but when I tried to build app, there is an error:

> SyntaxError:
>   js/source/components/Button.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (9:5)

My code (starts from 9 line):

```
type Props = {
    href: ?string,
    className: ?string,
}

const Button = (props: Props) =>
    props.href
        ? <a {...props} className={classNames('Button', props.className)}/>
        : <button {...props} className={classNames('Button', props.className)}/>
```

Is it possible to create my own type or it is some old standard?
Thanks for any comment!

Comment: there is no type in javascript - you should checkout typescript or flowtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you see in the book is using [flowtype](https://flow.org) by Facebook. It is an augmented syntax on top of standard js, and it needs to be transpiled back to normal js code by `babel` before you can actually run it.

I believe Stefanov includes setup instructions in his book. Check the part you skipped, or visit flowtype's site for instructions.

As of up-to-date-ness, well, I'd say [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) by Microsoft is getting more attention. These two are competitors, solving same problem. I personally think typescript is doing a better job.